# How to execute make in all subdirectories

Tags: find, make, macos

I have a few directories which have a Makefile in them.

I've make this script to run those Makefiles if they exist:

```bash
find . -name "Makefile" -exec sh -c 'make re -C "$1" $(dirname "$0")' {} \;
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I get this error:

```
make: the `-C' option requires a non-empty string argument
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
  -B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets.
  -C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
[...]
```

But when I replace `make re -C` with `echo` or `printf` it works fine...

```bash
find . -name "Makefile" -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1" $(dirname "$0")' {} \;
# or
find . -name "Makefile" -exec sh -c 'echo "$1" $(dirname "$0")' {} \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code uses two arguments, `$0` and `$1`, but you only ever pass something in `$0`, leaving `$1` empty.  This causes `make` to complain in the way you show.

You *could* fix this by simply dropping `"$1"` from your command (and quoting the command substitution around `dirname`) if you want to, assuming your `make` does not mind having operands and options in a mixed-up order, but I'll give you a few other ideas too.

---

The below two commands finds all regular files called `Makefile` in or below the current directory and then uses `make -C` to make the `re` target in each directory where such a file was found.

```bash
find . -name Makefile -type f -exec sh -c 'make -C "${1%/*}" re' sh {} \;
```

or

```bash
find . -name Makefile -type f -exec sh -c '
  for pathname do
      make -C "${pathname%/*}" re
  done' sh {} +
```

In the second command, I've changed the `sh -c` script to make a loop over as many found pathnames as possible rather than just a single name.

I have replaced `dirname` in both commands with a standard parameter expansion that removes the last pathname element from `$pathname`. We know there is at least *one* slash in the pathname even if the `Makefile` file was found in the current directory, which makes this safe; this is otherwise an edge case where you *don't* want to replace `dirname` with a quicker substitution.

---

An even snappier variant that does not use `make` with its `-C` option is to run `make` with the (non-standard) `-execdir` predicate from `find`:

```bash
find . -name Makefile -type f -execdir make re \;
```

This causes `find` to change the working directory for `make` to the directory where the `Makefile` file was found. The benefit of this variant is that it executes `make` directly without dealing with a `sh -c` script.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `make -C` it's easier to just `cd` into the directory.

This implementation works fine:

```bash
find . -name "Makefile" -exec sh -c 'cd "$(dirname "$0")" && make re' {} \;
```